# Run Cron job in node js

Tags: node.js, express

I'm using Expressjs
At /routes/index.js i have:

```
app.group('/test', test => {
    const testHandler = new testHandler();
    test.get('/test-action', testHandler.testAction.bind(testHandler));
  });
```

At /test/handler.js i have

```
export class testHandler {

  constructor() {
  }

  /**
   * @param req
   * @param res
   * @param next
   * @returns {*}
   */
  async testAction(req, res, next) {
    // todo code here
  }
}
```

I want to create a cronjob to run that route ( for example localhost:3000/test/test-action ) twice an hour.
With PHP i can do it by `* */2 * * * php /path_to_webroot/index.php param1 param2`
Is there a similar way to do it with Nodejs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `node-cron`. It uses similar syntax as you are using in php.

```
# min hour mday month wday command
*/15  *    *    *     *    some-command
```

to schedule some-command to run every 15 minutes, `node-cron` would use a similar syntax to specify the time to run:

```
'0 */15 * * * *'
```

Well, you need to define your express routes normally. Then inside your cron function you would make a request to that express route you have defined.

```
request('http://localhost:3000/test/test-action', function(error, response, body) {
        if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
            console.log('im ok')
            // console.log(body) 
        }
    })
```

You can use `request inside your corn job. This way your API will get called every specific time.

Comment: I know node-cron but in my scenario, how to use it?
For example i can use `nodemon --exec babel-node -- ./server/app.js` to start my node app, but i want to run /test/test-action only.
With PHP i can use `php /path_to_web_root/index.php testController testAction`

Comment: Updated my answer!

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply.
Is that the only way?
That's the official way for node or work around solution?
If i use `* */2 * * *curl http://localhost:3000/test/test-action`, it'll be more simple?

Comment: @duc why do you want to do that way specifically?  you can do that in your machine as well but what will happen if you turn off your machine?

Comment: @Naresh i just want to find the best solution. If i turn off my machine, node app is killed and http://localhost:3000/test/test-action can't work, it means xMayank's solution and mine can't work too?

Comment: you would want to deploy your app to some server and then you won't have to start the cron job manually. your node server will take care of it. @xMayank solution sounds good.

Comment: ok, i think i'll go with node-cron
thank @xMayank, Naresh for your help and kindness